# Type Error: non-precise type array(pyobject, 2d, F)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba, jit

| id | session | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | online | 1.3 |
| 2 | live | 1.9 |

| id | session | no | Graded |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | online | 1.3 | A |
| 1 | online | 1.3 | B |
| 1 | online | 1.3 | C |
| 2 | live | 1.9 | A |
| 2 | live | 1.9 | B |
| 2 | live | 1.9 | C |

Those are D1 and D2. To turn these dataframes into arrays, I am using D1.values and D2.values.

```py
@njit
def Simulation (D1, D2):
    dfs=[]
    uniqueids=np.unique(D1[:,0])
    for k in range(D2.shape[0]/25)):
        for i in uniqueids[25*k:25*(k+1)]:
            mask=(D1[:,0]==i)
            temp=D1[mask]
            dfs.append(temp)
        return dfs
```

I get the error:

> TypingError: non-precise type(pyobject,2d,F)
> During: typing of argument at /temp/ipykernel_383453/178169486.py(5)

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm new to using the numba Library. My code was in Pandas and now I am trying to change it to bumpy arrays and I am getting that error after changing D1 and D2 from dataframes to arrays.

Comment: Welcome to So! If you want to clarify your question, [edit] it rather than adding a supplementary comment. That way all of your problem statement is in one place.

Comment: Why did you tag it `pandas`? Is any of the variables a DataFrame in disguise?

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example that produces this error? That is, with initial data created (e.g., a sample array, or even a sample DataFrame converted to an array).

Comment: I wonder if `D2.shape[0]/25` should be `D2.shape[0]//25`: use integer division, so it's guaranteed the result is an integer.

Comment: Thank you for assistance. I made some edits to my question. Your help is highly appreciated.